# How to sum children process memory with /usr/bin/time

Tags: linux, unix, memory

Let's say I have a program that takes up memory such as

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int * a = (int *) calloc (10000000, sizeof(int));
    sleep(1);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

and let's say I want to run this program muliple times using something like the parallel command.

```
parallel ./a.out ::: `seq 1 10`
```

Using /usr/bin/time will return the memory of the parallel command, but not the memory of a.out. Is there a way to get all of the memory of the instances of a.out and sum them up while parallel is running? I don't want to run a.out ten times and manually add up the memory because it wouldn't be the actually memory usage during parallel's runtime.

Comment: I have the same problem